# Ignore last 5 minutes in intraday High Low

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot Intraday high , I was able to plot using below

```
tHigh = security(t,"D",high , gaps=igaps,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
tLow = security(t,"D",low , gaps=igaps,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

But I want to ignore last 5 minutes of high low data.Because when price is making highs , that position is always marked as high.

Also someone please tell me what is lookahead and gaps , There is no clear explanation anywhere.

Comment: There is a pretty clear explanation of lookahead and gaps in the User Manual [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#barmerge-gaps-and-lookahead).

As for your question:

1. What chart resolution are you using?

2. Do you want to ignore the last 5 minutes of every session or the last 5 minutes of the chart, wherever you are in the session?

Comment: 2. I want to ignore last 5 minutes of intraday while calculating high / low of the day

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of the code in [this FAQ answer](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-period-of-time) with session constraints to accommodate your need. It will only work on chart resolutions <= 5min. It will require the proper hours corresponding to your markets to be set in your script's *Settings/Inputs*:

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("Periodic hi/lo", "", true)
showHi = input(true, "Show highs")
showLo = input(true, "Show lows")
srcHi = input(high, "Source for Highs")
srcLo = input(low, "Source for Lows")
period = input("D", "Period after which hi/lo is reset", input.resolution)
timeAllowed = input("0930-1555", "Allowed hours", input.session)

timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed)
var hi = 10e-10
var lo = 10e10
// When a new period begins, reset hi/lo. Only update hi/lo when time is allowed.
hi := change(time(period)) ? srcHi : timeIsAllowed ? max(srcHi, hi) : hi
lo := change(time(period)) ? srcLo : timeIsAllowed ? min(srcLo, lo) : lo

plot(showHi ? hi : na, "Highs", color.blue, 3, plot.style_circles)
plot(showLo ? lo : na, "Lows", color.fuchsia, 3, plot.style_circles)
```

You can see here how the last 15:55 bar isn't taken into account in calculating the high:
[image]

---

Concerning the `gaps=` and `lookahead=` parameters of `security()`, you may find it useful to explore our [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) indicator. It shows values plotted using all combinations of settings for both parameters and which are best to avoid repainting:

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you so much , really useful , where can i set the parameter to ignore last 5 mins to last 10 mins...

Comment: That's controlled with the session information stored in the `timeAllowed ` variable which you can change in the script's *Settings/Inputs*. To ignore last 10 minutes, use `0930-1550`.

Comment: Hi , what is 0930-1550 ? I am from india my market timings are from 9.30 am to 3.30 pm

Comment: Like I said in the answer, hours will require adjusting for your markets. If you want to shave off 10 minutes from your market hours, then use `0930:1520`, no?

Comment: Ok but problem is what if I was at 10.30 pm , still I want to show previous low.